# creating a Paging List View in MFC

Tags: mfc, listview

How can I create a List View (or List Ctrl) with paging ?
that means that whenever there are too many items in the List Ctrl, those items are organised in different pages.

hope u get wht i mean.

It would be better if there is already such control built (for example in Codeproject).

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need paging? If you're trying to solve the problem of loading many items taking too long, the best answer is Owner Data. This allows you to provide data on the fly only for the displayed items. It works great.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774735(VS.85).aspx)